# How to check whether data contains an image or not in Php

Tags: php, image

I am getting data from a database and I want to check whether the data contains an image or not. I tried with following code and I want to know if is this a good solution for this.

```
$headers = get_headers('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/999921405858680857/1011168600410820679/1656572127-blog-2.JPG', 1);
if (strpos($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/') !== false) {
    echo "Work";
} else {
    echo "Not Image";
}
```

Comment: _"I am getting data from database"_ - But that code doesn't have anything to do with any data from a database? You're just fetching the headers of some discord URL? Please add some more details here. Are you getting the URL's from the database, or are you asking how to use the posted code for other data from the database? If so, we need to know more how you've stored things. It's too unclear atm.

Answer (score 1):

No. When verifying files, you should never rely on headers. Headers can easily be modified by whomever is providing you with the file. A much more reliable option would be to use the [PHP fileinfo extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

```php
<?php

// Fileinfo extension loaded
$finfoAvailable = false;

// Download the file
$imgUrl = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/999921405858680857/1011168600410820679/1656572127-blog-2.JPG';

// Use basename() function to return the base name of file
$file_name = basename($imgUrl);

// Get the file with file_get_contents()
// Save the file with file_put_contents()
if (file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($imgUrl)))
{
    // Checks if fileinfo PHP extension is loaded.
    if (!extension_loaded('fileinfo'))
    {
        // dl() is disabled in the PHP-FPM since php7 so we check if it's available first
        if(function_exists('dl')
        {
            // Check if OS is Windows
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
            {
                if (!dl('fileinfo.dll'))
                {
                    echo "Unable to load fileinfo.dll extension";
                }
                else
                {
                    $finfoAvailable = true;
                }
            }
            // OS is something else than Windows (like linux)
            else
            {
                if (!dl('fileinfo.so'))
                {
                    echo "Unable to load fileinfo.so extension";
                }
                else
                {
                    $finfoAvailable = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Unable to load PHP extensions as dl() function is not available";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $finfoAvailable = true;
    }

    // If fileinfo is available
    if($finfoAvailable)
    {
        $finfo = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
        $mtype = finfo_file( $finfo, $file_name );

        if(strpos($mtype, 'image/') === 0)
        {
            echo "File is an image";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "File is not an image";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "PHP extension fileinfo in not available";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "File downloading failed.";
}

?>
```